# Find critical value to test claim that $μ_1 = μ_2$

Tags: statistics

Find the critical values to test the claim that μ1 = μ2 . Two samples are random, independent, and come from populations that are normal. The sample statistics are given below. Use α = 0.05.

$n_1 = 14,\; n_2 = 12$

$\bar X = 15,\; \bar Y = 16$

$S_1 = 2.5,\; S_2 = 2.8$

Would appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance on how to start solving this problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of the two-sample t test. 
(1) The pooled test makes the assumption that the two population variances are equal, computes the 'pooled' variance estimate as
$$S_p^2 = \frac{(n_1 - 1)S_1^2 + (n_2-1)S_2^2}{n_1 + n_2 -2},$$
and uses the statistic
$$T = \frac{\bar X_1 - \bar X_2}{S_p\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2}}},$$
which has Student's t distribution with $n_1 + n_2 -2$ degrees of freedom under the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2.$

(2) Because the pooled test can perform quite badly if the two population variances are not equal, most practitioners prefer to routinely use the Welch (separate variances) test
which does not assume equal variances and uses the test statistic
$$T^\prime = \frac{\bar X_1 - \bar X_2}{\sqrt{\frac{S_1^2}{n_1} + \frac{S_2^2}{n_2}}},$$ which has approximately Student's t distribution with 
degrees of freedom $\nu$ found according to a formula. The result of the
formula is that $\min(n_1 - 1, n_2 - 1) \le \nu \le n_1 + n_2 - 2,$ with
$\nu$ nearer the larger value if $S_1^2 \approx S_2^2$ and nearer the smaller value if the sample variances differ greatly. If the Welch test is not discussed
in your textbook, you can read about it and find the formula for the degrees of freedom on [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test).

The bad behavior of the pooled t test can be especially serious if sample
sizes are unequal and the smaller sample has the larger variance.

Results from Minitab for the pooled test are as follows:

```
Two-Sample T-Test

Sample   N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       14  15.00   2.50     0.67
2       12  16.00   2.80     0.81

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  -1.00

T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
  T-Value = -0.96  P-Value = 0.346  DF = 24
Both use Pooled StDev = 2.6417
```

Because the P-value exceeds 5%, you would not reject the null hypothesis
at the 5% level of significance. (This P-value is for a two-sided test; that
is the alternative hypothesis is $H_a: \mu_1 \ne \mu_2.)$ I will leave it to you to consult a printed
t table to find the critical value for a test at the 5% level, verify the value of $S_p.$ and to
do the other intermediate computations required to find the $T$ statistic.

For the Welch test the Minitab output is as follows:

```
 Two-Sample T-Test

 Sample   N   Mean  StDev  SE Mean
 1       14  15.00   2.50     0.67
 2       12  16.00   2.80     0.81

 Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
 Estimate for difference:  -1.00

 T-Test of difference = 0 (vs ≠): 
   T-Value = -0.95  P-Value = 0.351  DF = 22
```

Notice that $\nu = 22;$ you should use the formula to verify this result. Then
find the critical value for a 5% level test, and perform the intermediate
computations necessary to get $T^\prime.$